# sftp errors with connection closed

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to sftp into an Amazon Linux system w/ a password.

I created an account, 'amitd', set the password, and I modified /etc/ssh/sshd_config to set 'PasswordAuthentication yes' and I bounced sshd.

I attempt to login via both ssh and sftp, no problem, everything is looking goog.

But, I want this account to be sftp only, so I edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config again, and I add:

```
Match User amitd
        ChrootDirectory /disk1/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        X11Forwarding no
```

and I created '/disk1/amitd' and make sure it's owned by amitd, and again bounce the sshd server.

Now, I try to login w/ ssh, and I get:

```
mjb@feynmann:~/PEMs_and_PPKs$ ssh  amitd@172.24.5.159
amitd@172.24.5.159's password: 
Connection to 172.24.5.159 closed by remote host.
Connection to 172.24.5.159 closed.
```

which is fine, that's expected.

When I try logging in w/ sftp, I get:

```
mjb@feynmann:~/PEMs_and_PPKs$ sftp amitd@172.24.5.159
amitd@172.24.5.159's password: 
Connection to 172.24.5.159 closed by remote host.
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

which makes no sense to me.

If I do this:

```
ssh -vvv amitd@172.24.5.159
```

I get:

```
<...omitted all logging before the password prompt...>
amitd@172.24.5.159's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 172.24.5.159 ([172.24.5.159]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 172.24.5.159 closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2396, received 1740 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13579383.0, received 9861488.5
debug1: Exit status -1
Connection closed
```

Help? Can anyone offer me a clue here?

Edit:
Added information:  I tried explicitly enabling internal-sftp, but still can't login.
C handed /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

bounced sshd, but still have error:

```
amitd@172.24.5.159's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 172.24.5.159 ([172.24.5.159]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 172.24.5.159 closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2396, received 1740 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1055821.0, received 766748.2
debug1: Exit status -1
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

Comment: Have you enabled the internal-sftp subsystem? ( `Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp`)

Comment: Thanks Brandon.  I tried changing 'Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server' to 'Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp' and bounced sshd, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "bounce"? Do you mean "restart"? It's best to avoid jargon that is not widely understood, and stick with standard English, 
when addressing a worldwide audience.

Comment: Yes.  "Bounce" means "sudo service sshd restart".

Comment: After re-reading the OP, I think `ChrootDirectory` may not be acting as you think it does.  It seems you want it to basically specify a new, secure home directory for the user.  Check the man page for sshd_config and carefully read the ChrootDirectory section - you'll see that it's setting up a chroot environment. For example: "This path, and all its components, must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group. After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory"

Comment: Thanks Brandon, you're absolutely right!  I changed /disk1/amitd to be owned by root, and it all works correctly now!  If you want to enter it as an answer, I'll accept it.